# Incomplete results from an intersection

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, intersection

I am trying to map the density of buildings in flood-prone areas. In order to do that, I created a grid of equal-sized squares. I want to intersect the layer of buildings with the grid so I can determine the density of at risk buildings in each square.
Problem is, the intersection doesn't seem to work.

On ArcGis : I get an feature class but only some of the buildings have been intesected, others are still astride two squares.

On QGis : I get an empty output.

Does anyone have an idea of what the problem could be ? Am I using the wrong tool or is there a problem with the data I am using ? ArGis also refuses to extract the data from selection layers I created from the buildings... I guess it could be damaged, but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Usually it's either different projections or topological errors in the data.

Comment: 1. Check geometry tool should be able to tell you if anything wrong with the data for ArcGIS processing.
2. There is projection on the fly. Try projecting data to the same spatial reference before intersecting to see how it'll look.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answers, I hadn't seen them. The projections were identical. There was indeed a problem with the data. The grid I used wasn't done properly and the squares only had three sides (weird I know). so it couldn't intersect anything. I just used the tool "entity (sorry I'm not sure that's the proper terme in english) to polygon" and made a few corrections to get a proper grid and it worked.